# How to load data from an other website with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

How to load specific data from an other website (other domain) with ajax?
For example text within a specific `<div>`.

Note: The `.load()` function in jQuery does not help.

Comment: If you're using jquery try http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ it should do what you want.

Comment: cross domain requests are not allowed via ajax

Comment: could this be maked through iframe

Comment: emaillenin cross domain requests are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a proxy on your own domain that request external html or json content and servers this for you.

See an example for this here: [JSON Proxy in Java / Play! Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183199/json-proxy-in-java-play-framework)